# Min-width and max-width are not working with flex, plus combine with flex direction

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the code bellow with two issues:

1. The big image is not centered. I want the small images(thumbs) to remain align to the left.
2. `min-width` on `class th` acts like a `max-width` and the real `max-width`
   doesn't matter.

What I want is the `th`to not get smaller than the `min-width`, even if the big image is smaller.

Also not go more than `max-width` if there are many thumbs. The thumbs should wrap bellow.

For the example I use pixels, but maybe use rem,% to avoid issues on smaller screens.

[image]

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
.th {
   display: flex;
   align-items: flex-start;
   flex-direction: column;
   margin: 0 30px 0 0;
   min-width: 30%;
   max-width: 60%;
   border: 1px solid blue;
  }

.cimage img{
   padding:10px;
   max-height: 200px;
   max-width: 200px;
}

.thumbs { 
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

.thumb { 
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="th" >
    <div class="items" >
      <div class="item">
        <div class="cimage"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"/></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbs">
      <div class="thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/></div>
      <div class="thumb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50"/></div>
   </div>   
  </div>
  <div class="text">
             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publish
</div>
```

Comment: I made the correction. I had it in scss, and change to css

Comment: you need to add `flex-shrink:0;`

Comment: I added an image, my issue is why thumbs do not wrap bellow, if max-width is reached ?

Comment: and to center simply use `margin: auto;` on the div of the image

Comment: if you want them to wrap you need to add `flex-wrap:wrap`

Comment: thanks; and centering the big image ?, I have justify-content: center, but doesn't seems to work

Comment: use margin auto on the div of the image

Comment: I added more relevant duplicates, let me know if they are helpful

Comment: no everything is solved, thank you